# Highchart Data is not supporting

Tags: json, variables, highcharts

I am working on HighChart.js for the last two weeks. But I am stuck on the below issue.

I am having data in console.log same as the data as:

```
[0.061047,0.061047,0.061047,0.061047,0.061048,0.061033,0.061033,0.061015,0.061015,0.061016,0.061013,0.061013,0.06102,0.061021,0.061035,0.061027,0.061019,0.061018,0.061016,0.061016,0.061014,0.061013]
```

But when I put **items** as a data, it shows nothing, but when I statically put the above data, the graph data has been shown. It is totally illogical issue that I am facing.

Please help me.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var items = [];
            var index = '';
            $.ajax({ 
            type: 'GET', 
            url: 'http://localhost/HighChart-Js/json_demo.txt', 
            data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) { 

                $.each(data, function(index, element) {

                    items += ','+element.price;

                });

                items = items.replace(/^,/, '');
                items =  "[" + items + "]";
                items =  $.trim(items);;


            }
        });

            setTimeout(function(){
            var d = new Date();
            d = d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
            var baseConfig = {
                        credits: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        chart: {
                            plotBackgroundColor: null,
                            plotBorderWidth: null,
                            plotShadow: false,
                            backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)'
                        },        
                        tooltip: {
                            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y:,.7f}</b>',
                            percentageDecimals: 1
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                                gridLineWidth: 0
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            area: {
                                allowPointSelect: true,
                                cursor: 'pointer',
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: false,
                                    color: '#000000',
                                    connectorColor: '#000000'
                                },
                                marker: {
                                     enabled: false,
                                     symbol: 'circle',
                                     radius: 2,

                                     states: {
                                        hover: {
                                           enabled: true
                                        }
                                     }
                                  }
                            }
                        }


            };
            console.log(items); // ITEMS VARIABLE SHOWS DATA IN CONSOLE BUT WHEN I PUT THE VARIABLE AS A DATA ABOVE, IT SHOWS NOTHING       
            var data1 = {

                         title: {
                            text: 'ETH'
                        },

                        subtitle : {
                           text: "Ethereum"  
                        }, 
                        xAxis : {
                               type: 'datetime'
                         },
                        yAxis: {
                                min: 0,
                                gridLineWidth: 0
                        },  
                        series: [{
                            name: 'Ethereum',
                            type: 'area',
                            data: items, // THIS IS THE ITEM VARIABLE THAT IS NOT WORKING HERE
                            allowDecimals: true,
                            pointStart: d,
                            pointInterval: 3600000
                          }]
            };



         $('#container1').highcharts(
            $.extend(baseConfig, data1)
        );

        }, 1500);


        });
        </script>
```

Sorry for the edit. json_demo.txt has following data.

```
[{"timestamp":1523430220,"tid":224440488,"price":"0.061047","amount":"0.37550269","exchange":"bitfinex","type":"buy"},{"timestamp":1523430220,"tid":224440487,"price":"0.061047","amount":"0.62669802","exchange":"bitfinex","type":"buy"},{"timestamp":1523430214,"tid":224440471,"price":"0.061047","amount":"0.26241442","exchange":"bitfinex","type":"buy"},{"timestamp":1523430214,"tid":224440467,"price":"0.061047","amount":"0.0698787","exchange":"bitfinex","type":"buy"},{"timestamp":1523430212,"tid":224440428,"price":"0.061048","amount":"7.43158","exchange":"bitfinex","type":"buy"},{"timestamp":1523430212,"tid":224440427,"price":"0.061033","amount":"3.0","exchange":"bitfinex","type":"buy"},{"timestamp":1523430212,"tid":224440426,"price":"0.061033","amount":"0.95899114","exchange":"bitfinex","type":"buy"},{"timestamp":1523430202,"tid":224440409,"price":"0.061015","amount":"3.0","exchange":"bitfinex","type":"buy"},{"timestamp":1523430202,"tid":224440408,"price":"0.061015","amount":"0.39885059","exchange":"bitfinex","type":"buy"},{"timestamp":1523430185,"tid":224440327,"price":"0.061016","amount":"0.02","exchange":"bitfinex","type":"buy"},{"timestamp":1523430184,"tid":224440324,"price":"0.061013","amount":"0.22349968","exchange":"bitfinex","type":"buy"},{"timestamp":1523430184,"tid":224440323,"price":"0.061013","amount":"0.43187032","exchange":"bitfinex","type":"buy"}]
```

Comment: remove complex array formation in ajax success function instead use `items.push(Number(element.price));` to form array

Comment: You format your data as a string. It needs to be an array. Instead of doing this: `items += ','+element.price;`, push the elements to an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Answer.

By using PARSE, JSON.parse(items)

Graph data has been shown.

Comment: You still should consider using `items.push` as suggested in the comments. Appending strings to an array doesnt make much sense.